# Removing users from site usgin C# is very slow

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to remove users from SharePoint site programatically (winform). The below code works but there are two problems

1. It takes bout ~1 minute to revoke access for one staff
2. During the execution of the tool, the site is unresponsive, So if i tried to remove access for 20 staffs then ~20 mins the site is unresponsive.

How can I revoke access without the performance side effect?

***Note**: PowerShell is not an option since it is blocked in our org.*

***SharePoint Version : 2008***

```
         using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SiteUrl))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < RevokeStaffList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var userToremove = RevokeStaffList[i];
                        SPUser user = null;
                            user = web.SiteUsers[userToremove];

                        if (user != null)
                        {
                            if (!user.IsSiteAdmin)
                           {
                                    web.SiteUsers.Remove(user.LoginName);

                           }
                        }
                 }
             }
```

Comment: 1 minute is too much, I don't have solution for you. But if the code is taking time then instead of winforms, you can create console application and then schedule it to run at off hours.

Comment: You could add some timer to your code to see which part is taking long (or just use debug mode to see where the main wait occurs). 1 min is very long wait. Do you have search turn on for crawling? if so it may affect the performance as your sec principals for site are changing and they need to be reflected (best practice for large sec changes is to pause the search crawl until you finish with your changes)

Comment: You can use console.log to output the windows time for each steps, see which command uses long time. Meanwhile, you can use sql profile to monitor the database, try to find the cause.

Comment: I've added log entries for each step now. Also,  made some improvements by RemoveByID for users and loading the fetching the `SiteUsers`  list into a variable. My org process will take time to get approvals, will update on the progress